# Field Title in Experience Editor showing '[Not set]' in Chrome

Tags: experience-editor

When editing pages in EE using Chrome, clicking on fields show the field details popup but with a '[Not set]' title [image] whereas in Firefox it shows the actual field name:

We're using Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 160519)

Comment: any browser console error or entries in chrome ?

Comment: Errors, no. But warnings that don't seem related: "SessionTimeout not found in settings scForm.Settings", "ApplicationCache is not declared", "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated...", "Use of the Application Cache is deprecated..."

Comment: please make sure you have same URL parameters in two browsers like sc_site=<sitename>&sc_db=master&sc_lang=<language>&sc_version=<NUMBER>

Comment: I copied and pasted it from one browser to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a js compatibility issue.
Our site uses hyphenator.js library which conflicted with the Sitecore's EE elements.
I updated the hyphenator.js file to exclude scChromeData and scWebEditInput classes from its processing logic and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please download the following Sitecore Support Patch [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhweubo1alrd27g/Sitecore.Support.1017770.zip?dl=0).

It is a fix about the Field Editor dialog has no header. If the patch does work, I would recommend you to contact Sitecore Support and ask them one which is compatible with your version.

As a side note, Sitecore responded that the patch is compatible with both Sitecore version 8.1 and 8.2.

The Sitecore Patch detail is: **Sitecore.Support.1017770**. The zip file contains an assembly and a config file.

1. Place the attached Sitecore.Support.101770.config file to the \App_Config\Include folder.
2. Place the attached Sitecore.Support.101770.dll assembly to the \bin folder.

Comment: the issue was occurring only in chrome browser. is patch for chrome browser issue ?

Comment: Not sure if it is for browser specific. I need to check this the team. But we were faced with the same issue.

Comment: @HishaamNamooya, thank you but this did not work... Could it a version issue?

Comment: It might be. I would suggest to create a support ticket at sitecore.